# What is the generalisation of unzip?

Tags: list, haskell, typeclass

Most methods I know from lists are actually special cases of some well-known type classes. Some examples of methods and the related type class:

- `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and `Functor`
- `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` and `Foldable`
- `forM :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]` and `Traversable`
- `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` and `Monad`

Possibly the list goes on (pardon the pun).

I'm wondering about the "deeper meaning" behind `unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])`. Can it be implemented using some famous instances of `[]` and, e.g., the functor instance of `(,a)`? Or some other instances? Ideally, I'd want to have a more abstract function with this type: `SomeClass m => unzip :: m (a, b) -> (m a, m b)`. Is there a class that will make this work?

Comment: [Data.Align.Unalign](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Align.html#t:Unalign)

Comment: Related: The "deeper meaning" behind _zip_ is being a [right adjoint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.3/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply take first and second projections:

```
gunzip :: Functor f => f (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
gunzip ps = (fmap fst ps, fmap snd ps)
```

But note that `gunzip` traverses `ps` twice unlike the usual `zip` for lists, so it's troublesome, because `ps` is not garbage collected after the first pass and stays in the memory, which causes memory leaks on big lists.

Comment: Good answer. I think it's also worth noting that `gunzip` specialized to `[]` is less efficient than `unzip` (it takes two passes instead of one).

Comment: I gather it can sometimes be faster, but memory leaks bite.

Comment: You can do this in one pass, most easily using `Control.Arrow`: `gunzip = fmap (fst &&& snd)`.

Comment: @chepner, it doesn't typecheck. `fst &&& snd ≗ id` and `fmap id ≗ id`. Hence your definition is `gunzip = id`.

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified and didn't look closely at my test result. `(fmap fst) &&& (fmap snd)` should work.

Comment: @chepner, this function is pointfree, but it doesn't mean that it traverses lists once. `(fmap fst &&& fmap snd) ps` immediately reduces to `(fmap fst ps, fmap snd ps)`, so it's the same function.

Answer (score 6):

Intuitively, the `unzip'` function has to tear down a structure holding `(a,b)` , and then build it up into two copies of the structure, the first of which contains the `a` and the second of which contains the `b`.

One possible generalization, already mentioned in another answer, is

```
unzip' :: (Functor t) => t (a, b) -> (t a, t b)
unzip' xs = (fmap fst xs, fmap snd xs)
```

This fits the bill, but one disadvantage is that it has to pass over the initial structure twice - once for each call to `fmap`.

---

The `Foldable` class describes structures which can be iterated over, building a result as we go. We can take advantage of this property to ensure that we only pass over the initial structure once (one call to `foldr`) but we still need to know how to build up copies of the structures again.

The `MonadPlus` type class provides ways to get an empty structure, and to combined two structures (a bit like higher-order `Monoid`) -

```
class Monad m => MonadPlus m where
  mzero :: m a
  mplus :: m a -> m a -> m a
```

With this, we can write

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Foldable (foldr)

unzip' :: (Foldable t, MonadPlus m) => t (a, b) -> (m a, m b)
unzip' = foldr f (mzero, mzero)
  where
    f (a,b) (as, bs) = (mplus (return a) as, mplus (return b) bs)
```

We can then do things like

```
>> unzip' [(1,2), (3,4)] :: ([Int], [Int])
([1,3],[2,4])
```

but also

```
>> unzip' (Right (1,2)) :: ([Int], Maybe Int)
([1],Just 2)
```

---

One final thought - it's a bit ugly that we need to call `mplus (return a) as`. It might be nicer to have a class like

```
class Listish m where
  null :: m a
  cons :: a -> m a -> m a
```

but I haven't really explored this bit of the design space.

Comment: But `unzip'` "linearizes" a structure: unzipping of a tree doesn't result in a tuple of trees but rather in a tuple of lists in disguise.

Comment: @user3237465 If the tree is a properly defined instance of `Functor`, then `fmap` will produce a tree, not a list. The type of `fmap` is `a -> b -> f a -> f b`, not `a -> b -> f a -> [b]`.

Comment: @chepner, I meant the second `unzip' = foldr f`.

Comment: That's not `Prelude.foldr`; it works with any `Foldable` type, not just lists.

Comment: There does seem to be a problem with the second `unzip'`, though; it only takes one argument, but it needs to supply two in addition to the function `f` passed to `foldr`.

Comment: @chepner I corrected that in the most recent edit (about 5 min ago!)

Comment: @chepner, it works with any `Foldable` like it's a list, i.e. `Foldable.foldr f z ≗ Prelude.foldr f z . toList`. But that doesn't matter, because when you return a `MonadPlus`, your structure is flat anyway. Though, it's possible to represent non-flat structures using flat `Monoid`s like [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmlist-0.9/docs/Data-FMList.html) and hence this is probably possible with `MonadPlus`, but then you need a smarter recursor than just `foldr`, which is far to generic to be easily expressible.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that this will always return flat structures.

Comment: This could still be useful if the `Foldable` and the `MonadPlus` are the same type!